# copy and move the component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm a newbie to react and redux, I'm having one issue and tried to find about it but still, I'm unable to find the solution for it.

Currently, I'm developing a system for drag and drop feature to generate a page using forms, text, button, etc components. Please note I'm not using any **npm** library for the **drag n drop**. Currently, I have done the portion of drag and drop using javascript drag and drop events, but the issue is currently I'm dragging and dropping the **HTML from the left bar components (text, button...) to the middle bar** content but in actuality, it should be converted into the **component**. I don't want to use any external plugin for this.

**My need**: my need is I want to drag n drop the component so I can apply all the **React** features on it.

Sorry all, if I'm asking any silly question to you guys. For example please take look on the image attached.[image: example image]

**In the above image, you can see:** There is a 'left bar, middle bar, and right bar'. From the left bar, I'll drag the text, button, etc, components to the middle bar. Once the component is dragged to the middle bar, I can click on it and on click of that right bar will be open with some options like font size, color, padding, etc. On change of these options, the component in the middle bar should reflect the changes.

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarity your question a little bit? I don't understand what do you mean by `I'm dragging and dropping the HTML content not a component`. How do you want to move the component?

Comment: Tip: try not to think about the drag and drop in terms of html or components.  Rather, let data drive it, especially since you are using Redux.  On drag start, store some information about what is being dragged.  On drop, dispatch an action that's based on the data stored from drag start.  For example, if I dragged an image, i might store the image source in Redux, then on drop, render the image in the component where it was dropped.

Comment: @JohnnyZabala Updated the question, plz take a look.

Comment: @kevin628 yes, I thought this way but there will be an issue in future like there are 100 of dragged components to the middle bar so every time I'll make a change it will run .map() to load components every time. This may create an issue. For a single change, it may affect the whole loop.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I suggest visualizing each component as an independent element that has its own data and events.
This might be a reduced case of the kind of the actions and data changes when the user interacts:

There are 3 main components:

- **List** (left bar) > **Element[]** (array of elements)
- **Content** (middle bar) > **Element[]** (array of elements)
- **Settings** (right bar) > **Setting[]** (array of settings)

---

*User starts dragging an element*: `onDragStart` fires on a List > Element. We track the data from this element to use it later.

*User drops the element in the middle bar*: `onDrop` fires on Content. We use the element data to update the Content elements adding a new Element.

*User clicks on an element to see its settings*: `onClick` fires on Content > Element. We update the list of settings and their values with the ones from the selected element in Settings > Setting.

---

There are different approaches to manage all this data flow.
You might want to use Redux where each component reads and writes to the store. A state similar to this:

```
{
    list_elements: [
        { id: 'unique_id1', name: 'Text', font_size: 13 },
        { id: 'unique_id2', name: 'Button', font_size: 12 }
    ],
    content_elements: [
        { id: 'unique_id3', name: 'Text', font_size: 11 },
        { id: 'unique_id4', name: 'Button', font_size: 8 },
        { id: 'unique_id5', name: 'Button', font_size: 9 }
    ],
    dragging_list_element: 'unique_id1',
    selected_content_element: 'unique_id4',
}
```

You might want to use [HTML5 Drag and Drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) data transfer property of the event and for the state simply keep the necessary data in a Root component state (parent to List, Content and Settings).
Or you could make use of React Context.

Hope this helps you figure out how to organise the app.